# Why couldn't we programmatically jump between viewControllers while programmatically setting up the initial viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm just using two viewControllers, say `viewControllerA` and `viewControllerB`. By using the following code in `AppDelegate.swift`, when the App is launched for the first time, it will set `viewControllerA` as initial viewController, and from the second time launch onwards, `viewControllerB` will be set as initial viewController.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    let defaultss = UserDefaults.standard
    if (!defaultss.bool(forKey: "firstTimes")) {  
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerA")

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    defaultss.set(true, forKey: "firstTimes") //set the key so it never executes again
    } else
    {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB")

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
     return true

}
```

It works fine. But if I use this code, then I could not programmatically jump between viewControllers either from `A` to `B` or `B` to `A`, using the following code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonA(_ sender: Any)
    {
            let ViewControllerB = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerB
            navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerB, animated: true)
    }


}

import UIKit

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func buttonB(_ sender: Any)
    {
         let ViewControllerA = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerA") as! ViewControllerA
            navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerA, animated: true)
    }

}
```

How can I achieve both, I should be able to detect the first launch and set initial viewController and I should be able to jump between viewControllers programmatically also.

I'm using Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: before  setting UIViewController as initial view controller as root view controller add them in UINavigationController.

Comment: What do you mean? @Dev_Tandel

Comment: see answer of @rv7284 : This is what i meant.

Comment: if you want to jump between view controllers , they should be in navigation controller.

Comment: Thats the very first step, I did it. It will navigate to other viewController too. The problem is, only when i use that launch detection code in AppDelegate.swift, its not navigating.

Comment: not getting you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In App delegate do this

```
let navC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
self.window?.rootViewController = navC
```

instead of

```
self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
```

Comment: This works, but it is creating a navigation bar, How can we remove it?

Comment: That is a all defirrent question but anyway, self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true